# Hibernate many-to-one foreign key annotation mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I use Hibernate 4 with Spring 3.1 and I have a problem with foreign key constraints which are generated from this mapping.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class O {
    private String oid;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "OidGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "OidGenerator", strategy = "com.evolveum.midpoint.repo.sql.OidGenerator")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 36)
    public String getOid() {
        return oid;
    }
    ...other getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Role extends O {
    private Set<Assignment> assignments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    public Set<Assignment> getAssignments() {
        return assignments;
    }
    ...other getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class User extends O {
    private Set<Assignment> assignments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    public Set<Assignment> getAssignments() {
        return assignments;
    }
    ...other getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Assignment extends IdentifiableContainer {
    private O owner;
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @MapsId("oid")
    @ManyToOne
    public O getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ContainerIdGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "ContainerIdGenerator", strategy = "com.evolveum.midpoint.repo.sql.ContainerIdGenerator")
    @Column(nullable = true, updatable = true)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
...other getters and setters
}
```

this produces schema like this...

```
create table Assignment (
    id bigint not null,
    owner_oid varchar(36) not null,    
    primary key (owner_oid, id)
);
create table Role (
    oid varchar(36) not null unique,
    primary key (oid)
);
create table User (
    oid varchar(36) not null unique,
    primary key (oid)
);
alter table Assignment 
    add constraint FKB3FD62ED72781986 
    foreign key (owner_oid) 
    references User;
alter table Assignment 
    add constraint FKB3FD62ED7276AE31 
    foreign key (owner_oid) 
    references Role;
```

that two constraints on Assignment.owner_oid should not be there. I can't save role/user with assignments because of them. I thought about other solution with join tables, but I looks too akward. Join table would look like

```
create table Role_Assignment (
    role_oid varchar(36) ...
    assignment_oid varchar(36) ...
    assignment_id bigint ...
    primary key (....)
);
```

but I have assignment.owner_oid annotated with @MapsId therefore in this join table first two colums would be always the same. Also I have couple more classes that extends from O.class, which means many join tables. How to disable that FK constraints on assignment table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move

```
...
public Set<Assignment> getAssignments() {
    return assignments;
}
```

to the abstract class, its the same in both classes.

And to answer your question - after you do that you can change your InheritanceType to JOINED (or SINGLE_TABLE, but you said you have many other subclasses so its not appropriate) - then you will have only one table with owner_oid column that whould be referenced from assignment.

Comment: I can't move getAssignments() method. But as you said I'll change InheritanceType to JOINED and in getAssignments() method I'll use `@ForeignKey("none")` annotation to disable FK constraint on User and Role. Therefore hibernate will generate only one FK constraint which references O, which is ok for me.

Comment: why can't you move getAssignments()? Maybe you can create super class only for user and role?

Comment: class hierarchy is fixed, I can't change it would break other things. I just need to persist it...somehow :) But I fixed FK generated by hibernate. Thanks for your ideas.